# Iterate through a Hash Map with string and list as parameters

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

i have a scenario where i had to loop through a HashMap to check for null values and generate a empty bean .The empty bean will again be added to a new map.

```
for (String course_date : shiftSet) {
        Bean courseBean = null; 
        boolean  valueExists = false;

                for (Entry<String, List<Bean>> entry: courseMap.entrySet()){

                    String studentDetail = entry.getKey();
                    String [] studentSet =  StringUtils.getArray(studentDetail , ",");
                    String studentId = studentSet[0];
                    String courseId = studentSet[1];

                    for(Bean resultBean : entry.getValue()){

                        if(course_date.equalsIgnoreCase(resultBean.getCourseDate()){
                            valueExists = true;
                        }
                }
                        if(!valueExists ) {
                            courseBean = new Bean();
                            courseBean.setStudent(studentId);
                            courseBean.setCourse(courseId);
                            List<Bean> courseList = entry.getValue();
                            courseList.add(courseBean);
                            outputMap.put(studentId+courseId, courseList);
                         }
            }
        }
```

The boolean value is always true even if it doesn't satisfy the inner loop condition.

Can anyone suggest a better solution to achieve the desired output?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Initialize the variable with `false` value in the first `for` loop...

Comment: Not related to your problem, but _please_ don't write `String value = entry.getKey();`.  An entry has a key and a value.  Let's not swap their names around.

Comment: @ Luiggi Can you help to explain with an example on how to determine the index of the loop for my case.Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @ David wallace.Apologies.I will take note of it in the future..Thanks

Comment: @jegadees moved my comment into an answer. Please to reply a comment, you should not separate the `@` from the `<username>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your `valueExists` variable is initialized before the `for` loop where is needed for every validation. Rewrite it as this:

```
//declare it here (regardless this "initial" value)
boolean valueExists = false;
for (Entry<String, List<Bean>> entry: courseMap.entrySet()) {
    //initialize it here
    valueExists = false;
    //...
    for (Bean resultBean : entry.getValue()) {
        if(course_date.equalsIgnoreCase(resultBean.getCourseDate()){
            valueExists = true;
            //also, add a break here since you already found the value
            //you don't need to keep iterating through the rest of items
            break;
        }
    }
    if (valueExists) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luiggi.I was trying out the same.But misplaced the declaration of valueExists part.If i declare exactly next the outer for loop , i a m getting a null pointer exception.Not sure why it is happening..

Comment: @jegadees I don't understand your comment. Maybe if you edit your question and add (do not remove anything from it) your new code with the stacktrace I could find the problem.

Comment: I am getting an error inside the loop when valueexists is false.The part where the empty bean is generated and added..

Comment: @jegadees again: edit your question, add four dashes, then below it add **your current code** and the **stacktrace of the exception**, otherwise you're a blind asking to another blind to explain the colors...

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 variables with the same name `value`. One is String the other boolean. I guess this ambiguity confuses us, yourself and the compiler. In fact your code should not even compile.

Comment: sorry its my mistake while copying the code..changed now..Thanks

Comment: This fixes any typo but not the main problem.

Comment: shouldn't this be a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Once, you find that dates are matching, then break out of the for loop. Because, you are iterating over the list, so your boolean variable will be false only if the last entry in the bean list is false.

See the code review, with possible working solution

```
for (String course_date : shiftSet) {
        Bean courseBean = null; 

            for (Entry<String, List<Bean>> entry: courseMap.entrySet()){

                // Declare this boolean variable inside, since you are dealing with a single entry in the map at a time.
                boolean matchCourseDate = false;

                //Declare variable with more meaningful naming conventions.
                String key = entry.getKey();
                String [] studentSet =  StringUtils.getArray(key, ",");
                String studentId = studentSet[0];
                String courseId = studentSet[1];

                // Since, you are iterating over the list, make sure once you found the date match break out if this loop
                for(Bean resultBean : entry.getValue()){
                    if(course_date.equalsIgnoreCase(resultBean.getCourseDate()){
                        matchCourseDate = true;
                    }

                    // If the match is found, break. Otherwise, keep going.
                    if(matchCourseDate) 
                        break;
                }

                // If no match is found, then create a new bean and put it into output map.
                    if(!matchCourseDate) {
                        courseBean = new Bean();
                        courseBean.setStudent(studentId);
                        courseBean.setCourse(courseId);
                        List<Bean> courseList = entry.getValue();
                        courseList.add(courseBean);
                        outputMap.put(studentId+courseId, courseList);
                     }
        }
     }
```

Comment: i am getting a null pointer exception inside the matchcourseDate equals false loop..When the bean was added to the list , error occurs..